# Flask-SQLAlchemy join

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I have a problem with join at flask-sqlalchemy. I am a beginner at database and flask.

These are my classes:

```
class Shopping(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shoppings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=False)
    price=db.Column(db.Float(10), index=True)
    date=db.Column(db.Date())
    s_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('shopping_types.id'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Alisveris yeri :{0}  Tutar :{1}  Tarih:      {2}'.format(self.product_name,self.price,self.date)

    def __list__(self):
        return [self.product_name,self.price,self.date]

class Shopping_Type(db.Model):
    __tablename__='shopping_types'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    type_name=db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=True)
    types = db.relationship('Shopping', backref = 'shopping_types', lazy = 'dynamic')
    def __repr__(self):

        return '{0}'.format(self.type_name)
```

when I try on python terminal and run:

```
select shoppings.product_name ,shoppings.price, shoppings.date, shopping_types.type_name from shoppings join shopping_types ON shoppings.s_type_id=shopping_types.id
```

query

I get what I want but when I run flask-sqlalchemy command:

```
rslt=db.session.query(spng).join(st)
spng:Shopping(class)
st:Shopping_Type(class)
```

I get only Shopping data.
I want to get Shopping + Shopping_Type data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
rslt = db.session.query(spng, st).join(st)
```

The result would be an enumerable of `tuples` of `(Shopping, Shopping_Type)`

Comment: Thank you Van. I tried your solution at python terminal and it worked thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
rslt = db.session.query(spng, st).filter(spng.s_type_id == st.id).all()

for x, y in rslt:
    print("Product ID: {} Product Name: {} Sopping Type: {}".format(x.id, x.product_name, y.tye_name))
```

type(rslt) is a tuple, contains elements as the number of tables joining.